# Long list of tabular figures inside minipage goes off page

Tags: tables, luatex, boxes, minipage, tabularx

Using the follow MWE, I'm able to create a beautiful lists of photos on the left and a caption on the right (similarly, I could also use the sidecaption package or floats directly).

MWE [LuaLaTeX]:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that when multiple photos or long (height) photos are added to the tabular environment, the photos go off of the page instead of a new page being created and going into the new page.

MWE [LuaLaTeX]:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{0cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} & Some text on the side.
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that outside of the minipage and tabular environments, everything works perfectly, but this isn't an option because I need a caption on the right side of the images and also need to ensure that LaTeX doesn't move pictures around randomly. Ideally I can keep everything inside the minipage and tabular enviornments.

MWE [LuaLaTeX]:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
    \flushleft
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name} \\
\end{document}
```

I have hundreds of images that need to be formatted as in the first MWE, so applying `\newpage` manually is not an option.

Is there a way to automatically move the images to new pages where necessary like it does in the last MWE?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A `figure` environment will never be split across pages.

Comment: Are there alternatives for keeping the figure's `H` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a separate figure for each image and to make sure the order is not altered you need only to specify the location options for each figure environment `[!htb]`. Also use `\vspace{-0.25cm}` to align text and figures correctly. No need for a `minipage` at all. See this modified code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name1} & Some text on the side1.
            \end{tabular}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 2} & Some text on the side 2.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 3} & Some text on the side 3.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 4} & Some text on the side 4.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 5} & Some text on the side 5.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 6} & Some text on the side 6.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 7} & Some text on the side 7.
            \end{tabular}
            \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{6cm}}
                \vspace{-0.25cm}
                \includegraphics[width=8cm]{name 8} & Some text on the side 8.
            \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output as you want:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute genius and lifesaver! Thanks a ton. This works perfectly.

Comment: This would be a lot more efficient if you simply omitted the `figure` environments

Comment: The `figure` environment has the advantage of evenly distributing the figures vertically in a page. Besides, no need for explicitly inserting new lines or paragraphs.

Comment: @AboAmmar that's not really an advantage, it's a lot less efficient (and if the list is too long you're likely to get a "too many floats" error, and it's a lot more markup than a blank line that is all that's needed to insert a paragrap[h break.

Answer (score 3):

the `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` is not doing anything as the `figure` environment is already effectively a minipage. minipages and floats never break over a page.

You could use a `longtable` for a multipage table or simply place each image and text in a paragraph outside any table or float:

```
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{name1} \parbox[t]{6cm}{some text}

\includegraphics[width=8cm]{name2} \parbox[t]{6cm}{some more text}

\includegraphics[width=8cm]{name3} \parbox[t]{6cm}{yet more text}
```

seems to be all you need. Possibly with `\raisebox` around the images to adjust the alignment.

Comment: I tried the longtable approach, but the same issue persisted. Is there another way that you're talking about?

Comment: Also, the reason that I have it inside a minipage/figure is so that LaTeX won't randomly move things around. Without them, LaTeX throws the images out of order.

Comment: @Shaku No. the minipage in that position does nothing

Comment: @Shaku if you used longtable and it did not break over a page then you used it incorrectly, it is hard to say what you did wrong if you do not give an example.

Comment: @Shaku If you use `\includegraphics` as shown in teh answer here not in a `figure` they will be printed in the order they appear in the source, they will not "randomly move" any more than words in a paragraph randomly move when typeset.

Comment: Take my first MWE and delete the minipage. Replace the tabular with a longtable and add a few more. You'll see that it goes off of the page. As for the `\includegraphics`, there may be something else in my document causing it to move around, but the accepted answer met all of my requirements, including fixing the "randomly moving around" issue.

Comment: @Shaku, of course, if you put a longtable inside a table environment it doesn't work: a table is effectively a minipage and is an unbreakable box.

Answer (score 3):

A `figure` environment is never split across pages.

If you want that something doesn't float, don't make it into a floating environment. Also, anything repetitive should be compressed into a new command.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm]{geometry} % 6+1+8=15
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example


\newcommand{\figureitem}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{#1}}%
  \hspace{1cm}%
  \parbox[t]{6cm}{#2}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\figureitem{name1}{Some text on the side 1}

\figureitem{name2}{Some text on the side 2}

\figureitem{name3}{Some text on the side 3 that should split across lines, to show the effect}

\figureitem{name4}{Some text on the side 4}

\figureitem{name5}{Some text on the side 5 that should split across lines, to show the effect}

\figureitem{name6}{Some text on the side 6}

\figureitem{name7}{Some text on the side 7 that should split across lines, to show the effect}

\figureitem{name8}{Some text on the side 8}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! The command helps clean the document up quite a bit.